# Reading a decrypted file into a ZipInputStream truncates first file sometimes

Tags: java, android, encryption, epub, skyepub

I'm working on an e-reader app (using [skyepub](https://skyepub.net/)) that basically downloads encrypted books into the file system (and it saves is decryption key in the database), and when the user tries to read it it loads the book into memory and decrypts it.

The problem is that some books have their first chapter truncated (epub books are actually zip files, with each chapter being a separate file).. this result in this dreaded error:

> this XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below

## what i tried

I've verified that the encrypted book is downloaded properly, b/c if I copy the file over to my desktop (from my rooted android) and run this command on it:

```
openssl aes-192-cbc -d -K *** -iv *** -in test.epub.encrypted -out test.epub
```

it works just fine. However if i pretty much try to do the same with the following android code

```
public ContentData getContentData(String baseDirectory, String contentPath) {
    if( contentPath.startsWith("/fonts/")) {
        ... // handle font suff
    }

    int secondSlash = contentPath.indexOf('/', 1);
    if( secondSlash == -1) return null;

    String bookEditionID = contentPath.substring(1,secondSlash);
    String zipEntryName = contentPath.substring(secondSlash+1);

    final ContentData data = new ContentData();

    try {
        InputStream stream = dbUtil.getBookStream(bookEditionID);
        if( stream == null) return null;

        final ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(stream);

        ZipEntry entry;
        do {
            entry = zip.getNextEntry();
            Log.e("Abjjad","looping through entry: "+entry);
            if( entry == null) {
                zip.close();
                return null;
            }
        } while( !entry.getName().equals(zipEntryName));

        Log.e("debug","going through data with entry: " +entry+", contentLength: "+entry.getSize());
```

see the method `dbUtil.getBookStream`:

```
public InputStream getBookStream( String bookEditionId) {
    BookInfo book = getBookInfo(bookEditionId);

    InputStream origStream = null;
    try {

        // Open the downloaded ePub
        origStream = openFileInput(bookEditionId + ".epub");

        // De-obfuscate the key
        SecretKeySpec sks = getObfuscationKeySpec(bookEditionId);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        byte[] decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(book.decryptionKey, Base64.DEFAULT));
        String keyPair = new String(decodedBytes);

        // Split the key and parse into binary
        int separator = keyPair.indexOf(':');
        byte[] key = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(keyPair.substring(0, separator));
        byte[] iv = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(keyPair.substring(separator + 1));

        c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding","BC");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return new CipherInputStream(origStream, c);
    } catch( Exception e) {
        try {
            if (origStream != null) origStream.close();
        } catch( Exception x) {}
        return null;
    }
}
```

then the log of entry.getSize() returns `-1` in the first code block.

## bonus (works on iOS!)

we wrote the same code in iOS, and it works perfectly (on the same book):

```
+ (NSData *)encryptKey:(NSString *)key ivParam:(NSString *)iv bookId:(NSString *)bookId
{
    NSString *keyPair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", key, iv];
    NSString *secret = [self getObfuscationSecretWithValue:bookId];

    NSData *data = [keyPair dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [[NSData dataWithHexString:secret] getBytes:keyPtr length:sizeof(keyPtr)];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted;
    CCCryptorStatus status = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                     NULL,
                                     [data bytes], [data length],
                                     buffer, bufferSize, &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (status == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    else {
        free(buffer);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

## update

i noticed that this truncation happens only after reading the toc (which seems like the *last* chapter from the above?).. from the logs:

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
getInputStream: /24748681/OEBPS/toc.ncx
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
looping through entry: mimetype
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/content.opf
looping through entry: OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat-ghayr-cover.png
looping through entry: OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat_fmt.png
looping through entry: OEBPS/template.css
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-2.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-1.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-3.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-4.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-5.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-6.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-7.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-8.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-9.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-10.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-11.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-12.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-13.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-14.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-15.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-16.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-17.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-18.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-19.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-20.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-21.html
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-22.html
looping through entry: META-INF/container.xml
looping through entry: OEBPS/images/277.png
looping through entry: OEBPS/toc.ncx
going through data with entry: OEBPS/toc.ncx, contentLength: 5549
returning data
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
getInputStream: /24748681/OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
looping through entry: mimetype
looping through entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html
going through data with entry: OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html, contentLength: -1
returning data
```

[image]

Comment: It's `ord('-')` < `ord('.')`, so have you considered it's the last one in the zip file, not the first one?

Comment: @tynn it's definitely the first one, based on exploring the contents of the epub file manually.. but what difference does that make anyways?

Comment: Wondering how you were able to use `dataWithHexString`, what library/framework?

Comment: There is something strange with your posted code. On your desktop machine you are using `aes-192-cbc`and a separate IV for decryption.

On Android you are using `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` and on iOS it looks like AES with ECB and PKCS7Padding. CBC and ECB are totally incompatible, therefore something is definitely wrong...

Comment: @Robert you mean on android i'm using CBC right? `c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding","BC");`

Comment: i changed the android code to use this line instead: `c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding","BC");`
but then got this error: `Can't open local ePub file '2196636321': java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: ECB mode does not use an IV`

Comment: @Robert never mind how the iOS does it.. the android code is perfectly consistent with the command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize()), getSize() may return -1 if the size is unknown.  This definitely happens in some zip files.  In those cases, you'll need to read the entire entry in order to determine its uncompressed size.

## Analysis

### Red herring

First of all the whole encryption decryption thing was a red herring.. simply copying the *same* epub/zip file and reading it using the same code resulted in the same page.. so this is a problem with the zip file itself rather than the decryption of it

### Zip documentation

As mentioned in the java doc, reading a zip file can actually return -1 if the content is unknown (which is exactly what's going on here).. as a matter of fact, we got the *same* zip file, unzipped it (on command line) then rezipped it with an increased compression level like so:

```
zip -9 -r filename.epub *
```

then we fed the same zip file to the existing code and it worked perfectly!

### solution

So this is the final code that worked:

```
    try {
        InputStream stream = abjjadDb.getBookStream(bookEditionID);
        if( stream == null) return null;

        final ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(stream);

        ZipEntry entry;
        do {
            entry = zip.getNextEntry();
            if( entry == null) {
                zip.close();
                return null;
            }
        } while( !entry.getName().equals(zipEntryName));

        data.contentLength = entry.getSize();
        data.lastModified = entry.getTime();
        data.contentPath = contentPath;

        InputStream s = zip;
        if( data.contentLength == -1) {
            Log.e("demo",new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()+":: entry \""+entry+"\" has contentLength -1, so we will work around");
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int nRead;
            // use buf to store data from the zip file entry in fixed size
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            while ((nRead = zip.read(buf)) != -1) {
                // dump that data into buffer, which is a growing buffer
                buffer.write(buf, 0, nRead);
            }
            buffer.flush();

            byte[] finalBuffer = buffer.toByteArray();
            Log.e("demo",new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()+":: entry \""+entry+"\" final data length: "+finalBuffer.length);
            data.contentLength = finalBuffer.length;
            s = new ByteArrayInputStream(finalBuffer);
        }
        final InputStream finalStream = s;
```

and the logs give us this

```
getContentData:: entry "OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html" has contentLength -1, so we will work around
getContentData:: entry "OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html" final data length: 2378
getContentData:: entry "OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html" has contentLength -1, so we will work around
getContentData:: entry "OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html" final data length: 2378
```

interestingly.. that size makes an exact match with the *actual* content length of that file `hayat-ghayr` if we run this on the command line:

```
$ unzip -l b17c024e-89f1-42f7-a546-91d46610cedb.epub 
Archive:  b17c024e-89f1-42f7-a546-91d46610cedb.epub
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
       20  01-27-12 11:17   mimetype
     2378  04-20-12 10:12   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html
     6436  02-06-12 11:06   OEBPS/content.opf
   112579  01-27-12 11:25   OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat-ghayr-cover.png
   182575  01-27-12 11:25   OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat_fmt.png
     7757  01-27-12 11:21   OEBPS/template.css
     5643  01-27-12 11:18   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-2.html
    20144  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-1.html
    65543  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-3.html
    59434  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-4.html
    66768  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-5.html
    49117  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-6.html
    65346  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-7.html
    74196  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-8.html
    73998  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-9.html
    61031  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-10.html
    68297  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-11.html
    72084  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-12.html
     2386  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-13.html
    61132  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-14.html
    46320  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-15.html
    32673  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-16.html
    88584  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-17.html
    56474  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-18.html
    52840  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-19.html
    80022  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-20.html
    50781  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-21.html
     2765  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-22.html
      265  01-27-12 11:17   META-INF/container.xml
    54942  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/images/277.png
     5549  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/toc.ncx
     1072  03-23-12 13:28   iTunesMetadata.plist
 --------                   -------
  1529151                   32 files
```

Comment: just for reference John-Paul Giganc did the final implementation, I updated his answer to share the complete picture