# why do certain zip files have unknown file content

Tags: java, android, zip, compression, skyepub

## background

I stumbled across this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768080/reading-a-decrypted-file-into-a-zipinputstream-truncates-first-file-sometimes)

## analysis

according to the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getSize()) for ZipEntry, sometimes requesting the size of a zipfile entry simply returns -1

However, running the command

```
$ unzip -l b17c024e-89f1-42f7-a546-91d46610cedb.epub 
Archive:  b17c024e-89f1-42f7-a546-91d46610cedb.epub
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
       20  01-27-12 11:17   mimetype
     2378  04-20-12 10:12   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr.html
     6436  02-06-12 11:06   OEBPS/content.opf
   112579  01-27-12 11:25   OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat-ghayr-cover.png
   182575  01-27-12 11:25   OEBPS/images/978-614-425-313-7-hayat_fmt.png
     7757  01-27-12 11:21   OEBPS/template.css
     5643  01-27-12 11:18   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-2.html
    20144  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-1.html
    65543  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-3.html
    59434  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-4.html
    66768  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-5.html
    49117  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-6.html
    65346  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-7.html
    74196  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-8.html
    73998  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-9.html
    61031  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-10.html
    68297  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-11.html
    72084  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-12.html
     2386  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-13.html
    61132  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-14.html
    46320  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-15.html
    32673  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-16.html
    88584  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-17.html
    56474  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-18.html
    52840  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-19.html
    80022  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-20.html
    50781  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-21.html
     2765  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/hayat-ghayr-22.html
      265  01-27-12 11:17   META-INF/container.xml
    54942  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/images/277.png
     5549  01-27-12 11:17   OEBPS/toc.ncx
     1072  03-23-12 13:28   iTunesMetadata.plist
 --------                   -------
  1529151                   32 files
```

shows that there is a content length for all the chapters.. 
but also, if we unzip the same file and rezip it again with stronger compression.. the zipFile java command returns the proper content size

## question

is this the zip library's fault or the original compression fault? how can we know?

## follow up question

see [How to access a zipEntry from a streamed zip file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809245/how-to-access-a-zipentry-from-a-streamed-zipfile)

Comment: to answer this we need the deep knowledge of zip format, UnZip implementation and java zip api implementation

Comment: UnZip can calculate the length the same way as you did (under the hood)

Comment: You would have to provide a short example of a zip file that shows the problem.

Comment: Some zip files contain directories as entry too (`OEBS/`). Maybe those are given a size -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZIP stores meta data inside the archive in a few different places ("local file header", "central directory" and sometimes a "data descriptor"). Only the "local file header" is in front of the file's content - the "central directory" is at the very end of the archive. Only the "central directory" holds the full truth, it is perfectly valid to not specify any size in the "local file header".

See section 4.4.8/4.4.9 in https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT which talks about the size fields

> If bit 3 of the general purpose bit flag is set, 
>          these fields are set to zero in the local header and the 
>          correct values are put in the data descriptor and
>          in the central directory.

The "data descriptor" immediately follows the compressed content of the entry - and thus is not available before reading the actual content of the entry when reading from a non-seekable stream.

When using `ZipArchiveInputStream` you obtain the `ZipEntry` as soon as the "local file header" has been read (because the underlying stream may not be seekable), so the size information may be missing. `ZipFile` uses `RandomAccessFile` under the covers and can read the "central directory" - as does `unzip` and friends - so they know more than `ZipArchiveInputStream`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the statement _it is perfectly valid to not specify any size in the "local file header"_

Comment: here is a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809245/how-to-access-a-zipentry-from-a-streamed-zipfile