# Java ZipInputStream skipping unused ZipEntry content, rather than draining it

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I'm trying to achieve an optimal reading of a *ZipEntry* content from zip. To achieve such I need the standard *ZipInputStream* to use *InputStream.skip* for not needed entry content rather than draining it.

As long as I understand from [ZIP (file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) wiki:

> Because the files in a ZIP archive are compressed individually it is possible to extract them, or add new ones, without applying compression or decompression to the entire archive. This contrasts with the format of compressed tar files, for which such random-access processing is not easily possible.

From this I assume that skipping not needed content is deterministic before uncompressing the entry's content using ZIP.

I however see that both *ZipInputStream*(Java standard) and *ZipArchiveInputStream*(apache) are draining the stream until the next entry rather than skipping it, which makes my use of it super inefficient.

I'm not completely aware of ZIP specification and seeing such a behavior of two majorly used ZIP APIs makes me think that it might be impossible.

Is it my understanding incorrect and such optimal behavior is not possible or what Java API do you suggest for reading Zip entries efficiently?

Comment: @Kayaman I can see your point, but I don't even need to check correctness on entries that are dropped, not to mention my data's integrity has already been verified. Doing a checksum of 1TB for 1KB is a overkill for me... As such I can't benefit from ZIP's tradeoff of bandwidth. Thank you will check!

Comment: It's an old class, even with native dependencies I noticed. I thought it didn't use skip because it's not supported on all `InputStreams`, but I don't think that's the real reason.

Comment: @Kayaman I saw your link, but as long as I understand it would require an implementation of a java.nio.FileSystem from my side, as I'm currently reading a file from not implemented FileSystem for my source.

Comment: @Kayaman reading from the network. I believe an answer should be given for an InputStream in general and not further expectations about it's origin.

Comment: Are you sure your stream is seekable? Streams from URLs and sockets normally wouldn't be

Comment: Consider to use the ZIP file system provider: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ZipInputStream` is a stream. You start by reading the LOC (local file header) for the first entry, read the entry (decompress, checksum, etc.), repeat until no more entries (or LOCs rather).

The end of the file/stream contains the directory for the whole zip contents for random access (or displaying zip file structure). When streaming data, you can't access the end of the stream. So even if you could seek, you wouldn't know where to seek to. You have to decompress to know when the data for the entry ends, then you get the LOC for the next entry and so on.

In this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809245/how-to-access-a-zipentry-from-a-streamed-zip-file-in-memory) it's said that the only source of truth is the central directory, so we can't rely on compressed size of an entry for skipping anyway.

Comment: The local file header notes the compressed size, right? Why can't you skip that?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm assuming it's the size the data compresses to, not the same as the bytes that can be skipped. Hmm, this might be worth testing since `ZipInputStream.closeEntry()` can be overridden and the `skip()` implemented trivially (I think).

Comment: Ah no, it just goes to the superclass `InflaterInputStream.skip()` which performs `read()` which inflates the data. It would require effort to subvert the design to actually *skip* bytes without inflating them, and even then I'm not convinced you can do it without the EOF directory.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the compressed size was not the amount to skip. I get the feeling like OP thinks this would reduce the amount of data transferred though, which is not normally the case.

Comment: Zip files can be tricky, and without the central directory things [get complicated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html). A custom solution might be possible, but it would be next to useless to implement. If avoiding the decompression and checksumming is the goal, then it's easier to invest in more CPU. If avoiding data transfer, then change the server to send only the wanted data (if possible).